# Best practice to deploy microservices into kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, microservices

Considering the following scenario:

- I have one main **heavy service** and many other **small microservices**.
- The **small microservices** are consumed only the **heavy service**.
- Only the main **heavy service** is exposed to the public internet.

What is the best practice to deploy those services into ?

All together in the same kubernetes cluster:

- The main **heavy service** LoadBalancer
- The other **small microservices** as ClusterIP (to protect them from public internet).

Is that a good approach ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some misunderstandings here.

There terminology about *microservice* is **not about size** but more an organizational thing. Ten years ago, the whole system was deployed as a *monolith* but now it is recommended that teams should not be bigger than 5-8 persons - and those teams should work in their own pace with their own *deployment cycle*. So the *monolith* has to be broken into smaller services. The services in such an architectural pattern is called for *microservices* - but not that they are *small* or *big*.

All your services should be deployed as a `Deployment` on Kubernetes, and the services should be *stateless*. So even the "main heavy service" should be stateless and possibly scaled to multiple replicas.

You are correct in that only services that **need** to be exposed to the Internet should be exposed to the Internet.

Wether your "heavy service" should be exposed with a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` actually depends more on what [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) you are using. E.g. If you are using *[Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)*, you should exposed it as a `NodePort` type. And yes, the other applications should have a `Service` of type `ClusterIP`.

It is worth noting that all Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) objects will provide *load balancing* functionality to the *replicas*. The service type, e.g. `LoadBalancer`, `NodePort` or `ClusterIP` is more about **how** the Service will be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, The good approach is to use **load-balancer** to manage the **low and high traffic** from the public. When you define min and max pods, it will increase the no of pods for heavy traffic and decrease for the low traffic automatically. And for the services you don't want to expose to the public make them **ClusterIP**.

Answer (score -1):

For other services, you can use k8s Horizontal Pod AutoScaling. In that case, pod numbers will scale based on traffic. It works particularly well for sudden spike and you can ensure proper usage of resources.

For easily integrating microservices and manage traffic flow among them, you can use Istio.